# Textbook problem - Struggling with polar coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics

Recently I am self-learning "Introduction to classical mechanics" by David Morin. There is a problem in chapter as stated below:

### Walking east on a turntable

> *A person walks at constant speed $v$ eastward with respect to a turntable that rotates counterclockwise at constant frequency $ω$. Find the general expression for the person’s coordinates with respect to the ground (with the $x$-direction taken to be eastward).*

Actually, I can fully understand the method used by the book but I tried to use another method to get the *x*-coordinate and somehow I cannot get it correct. Could anyone explain why the two methods are not coherent please?

---

**Solution by the book**

[image]

$$\dot x=v-u\,sin\,\theta \quad... (1) $$
$$\dot y=u\,cos\,\theta\quad...(2)$$
$$u=r\omega, \,y=r\,sin\,\theta, \, x=r\,cos\,\theta\quad...(3)$$

By substituting equations (3) into (1) and (2), we get

$$\dot x=v-y\omega\quad...(4)$$
$$\dot y=x\omega\quad...(5)$$
By differentiating (4), we get
$$\ddot x=-\dot y\omega\quad...(6)$$
By substituting (5) into (6), we get
$$\ddot x=-\omega^{2} x\quad...(7)$$
Finally, the solution of (7) is
$$x=x_mcos(\omega t+\phi)$$
To cater for easy comparison, I choose an initial condition "At *t*=0, *x*=0", so
$$x=\frac{v}{\omega}\,cos(\omega t-\frac{\pi}{2})$$
$$x=\frac{v}{\omega}\,sin\,\omega t$$

---

**My method**

According to my knowledge, radial velocity is only contributed by component of v in alignment with the radial direction, so
$$\dot r=v\,cos\,\theta$$
$$\theta=\omega t$$
By substituting and integrating both sides of the equations,
$$r=\int v\,cos\,\omega t \,dt$$
$$r=\frac{v}{\omega}\,sin\,\omega t$$
Finally,
$$x=r\,cos\,\omega t=\frac{v}{\omega}\,sin\,\omega t\,cos\,\omega t$$

---

*x*-coordinate by the book method: $x=\frac{v}{\omega}\,sin\,\omega t$

*x*-coordinate by my method: $x=r\,cos\,\omega t=\frac{v}{\omega}\,sin\,\omega t\,cos\,\omega t$

Here, we can see that my answer has an extra cosine function inside. Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong in this question? Thank you so much!

---

**Edit 1 (15th August)**
I have made a mistake in assuming $\theta=\omega t\; (or\, \dot \theta=\omega)$. The correct expressions are

$$\dot \theta=\omega -\frac{v}{r}sin\,\theta$$
$$\dot r=v\,cos\theta$$

May I know is there anyway that I could use to solve *r*(*t*) and $\theta (t)$ without using cartesian coordinates?

Comment: If the person is walking from the center towards the edge of the platform, shouldn't x spiral but eventually increase with time? I'm not asking about your solution, even the textbook solution confuses me. Also, in equation 3 you write that v= r omega... but isn't v the walking velocity? r omega is the angular velocity of the disk which has nothing to do with the walking speed, no?

Comment: " eastward with respect to a turntable " I do not understand. Eastward is only defined in terms of the ground reference frame, so to me the persons coordinates are just $x = v t$ and the motion of the turnable plays no role here.

Comment: @P.C.Spaniel Sorry for the typo! It should be u = r omega. The trajectory is seemingly spiral because you imagined that the person can escape from the turntable, which is an illusion (I guess). If you think of a turntable with infinitively large radius, then you can easily imagine that the person cannot escape from the turntable and he will have a circular path on the table instead.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I guess the question means that the person is moving to the east at whatever point on the turntable.

Comment: My confusion arose because the sentence "A person walks at constant speed v eastward with respect to a turntable" made me think that the personis walking east relative to the turntable. In other words: If we define comoving axis x' and y' that start align with the inertial frame on the ground and then start rotating, I thought that the person was moving with constant speed in x'. That would mean that from their point of view they are walking on a straight line through the turntable. However, the person is actually moving east relative to the inertial frame!

Comment: The person actually has constant v in the x direction defined by the inertial coordinates on the ground. So I think saying "walks at constant speed eastward with respect to a turntable" is incorrect or very misleading.

Comment: @P.C.Spaniel I see what you mean! So maybe we can stick with the idea that the person walks to the east on whatever points on the turntable. If that's the case, then the book's solution makes sense to me. However, I find it difficult to solve r(t) and theta(t) as stated in my edit section. Can you provide some insights for me? Thank you!

Comment: Usually solving differential equations involves precisely doing a change of coordinates to use the symmetries of the system. In this case, since motionis is in x, it breaks the rotation symmetry and thus solving the equations in polar coordinates seems hard. There's nothing wrong with that.

If you really want to solve it in theta and r, I would solve for r on the theta equation, and then take a time derivative, such that the equation reads r dot = things proportional to theta. And then I'd replace r dot there from the other equation to get an equation that only depends on theta.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

$\theta = \omega t$

is incorrect. When $\theta \neq 0,180$ then some of his "eastward" walking contributes to the angular velocity, namely $\dot{\theta} = \omega t + \frac{v}{r}\sin\theta$

Comment: Oh! I understand it now but I guess you should be writing   dot =  - / sin ? If that's the case, is that anyway that I can use to find expression of r without using the cartesian coordinates? Thx!